# Toggle with icon change

Tags: javascript

I have toggle and working.
Now I want include icon, this not working.

```
function myFunction(#menu) {
            var add.icon = item.nextElementClass;
            if (o.display === "block") {
                o.display = "none";
            } else {
                o.display = "inline-block";
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

`add()` is present on [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

Try

```
icon.classList.add('icon-up-dir');
```

Comment: @mamum - icon not changing

Comment: icon not changing

Comment: @Rju, I will request you to create an executable code snippet of the issue (using `<>` icon)

Answer (score 1):

With native js do simply

```
 element.classList.toggle('icon-up-dir');
```

For example [toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_classlist_toggle)

Comment: icon not changing

Comment: if it doesn't work the reason is not toggle method.